# SSIS convert to date issue

Tags: sql, ssis

im developing an ssis package.

while im in the sql server , there is a field that contains a text string , for example:

December 13, 2008

and so on...

i want to convert it to 2008-12-13 00:00:00.000 
or 2008-12-13 (its same for me)

so, in the sql server i can do it with this statement:

SELECT convert(datetime,myfiled, 107)

FROM ....

the question is , what is the equivalent statement to it within  the SSIS 2008 ? (with derived column)

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Did you try simple type cast:
`(DT_DBDATE) [MyField]`
?